# How to customize DataGrid header?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, templates, datagrid

How can I customize DataGrid Header?
This picture shows what I want to do...
[image: screenshot]

I try this, but it not working...

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Název modelu"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Cena bez DPH"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Cena s DPH"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
```

Can you help me, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the [HorizontalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment.aspx) to `Center` on your `TextBlock`

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
           Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Cena s DPH"></TextBlock>
```

You can start here to read more about the [WPF Layout system](http://wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html)

You also need to set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` to for the `DataGridColumnHeader`

Add this to the `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Comment: @SebastianBusek I've tested outside a DataGrid... to make it work see my updated answer. Now the header will occupy all the space. You can play now with ColumnDefinition.Width's and the Allignments to get your result.

Comment: Working! Thank you. :) Btw: where do you get this knowledge?

Comment: There is an app called [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) which can visualize any WPF app's visual tree. And I used that to find out which causes the header to shrink it was the `DataGridColumnHeader` and luckily there was a way to configure it with the `HeaderStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Width="*"  on the ColumnDefinitions